# Remotely execute a script ( batch/powershell) in windows from linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, scripting

I have a bunch of Batch and Powershell scripts in my Ubuntu machine and I want to remotely execute them on windows and retrieve their results using python. 
PS: I've already tried paramiko but it only works when the scripts in question are already on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it "only works when the scripts in question are already on the remote machine". You can't "remotely" execute a local program (script, whatever), it has to be on the machine where it's supposed to be executed. The solution is plain simple: upload the script on the remote machine, then use paramiko to execute it.

Comment: It sounded obvious to me as well but the thing is that I'm making a web app that's running on a Linux server and can do some analyses on both Linux and windows machines, so I wanted to avoid copying the scripts and deleting them whenever the user started analyzing. Anyway, thank you for your answer.